# UnsupportedOperationException with use fetch instead of join

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I use spring boot 2 with spring data jpa and hibernate implementation
I do a custom search

```
public Page<Samples> advancedSearch(SamplesSearchDto search, Pageable page) {
        Specification<Samples> specification = genericAdvancedSearch(search);

        return this.findAll(specification, page);
    }
```

My genericAdvancedSearch method

```
Specification<Samples> specification = (Root<Samples> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

    Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
    Join<Samples, Samplings> samplings = (Join) root.join("sampling", JoinType.INNER);

    ...

    return p;

};
return specification;
```

that work but I would like to use fetch to reduce sql query who are done.

I tried root.fetch... but get

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null     at
>   java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:262)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilderImpl.treat(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:1400)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilderImpl.treat(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:1113)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   com.mermacon.lcm.repository.SamplesRepositoryImpl.lambda$genericAdvancedSearch$39e4c45a$1(SamplesRepositoryImpl.java:88)
>   ~[main/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria(SimpleJpaRepository.java:694)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:625)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:583)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:386)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]

Comment: you should also show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: like it's wrote: root.join work root.fetch don't work.

Comment: paste all code of genericAdvancedSearch